# insertion in a self referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have a table

```
Table
{
ID int primary key identity,
ParentID int not null foreign key references Table(ID)
}
```

how does one insert first row into a table?

From a business logic point of view not null constraint on ParentID should not be dropped.

Comment: Intersting question. Is it even possible to reference to yourself? How can you even create 1 records if it is newly created?

Comment: What row is the parent of your first row?

Comment: For first row ParentID should be ID. If I want to use multiple roots in my tree structure then any root has ParentID == ID. Therefore the question can be expanded as - how can I insert root rows? Can stored procedure use SCOPE_IDENTITY to make this insert?

Comment: @Nezreli I've updated my answer to do what you're after. One thing I'm not entirely sure is if 2005 behaves differently from 2008R2 which I'm using at the moment. If you could validate that, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Nezreli Have you resolved the issue? What's the outcome?

Comment: I'll try to use your solution on one example to see if it's stable enough for wide implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server, a simple INSERT will do:

```
create table dbo.Foo
(
ID int primary key identity,
ParentID int not null foreign key references foo(ID)
)
go

insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (1)

select * from dbo.Foo
```

results in

```
    ID          ParentID
----------- -----------
    1           1
```

If you're trying to insert a value that will be different from your identity seed, the insertion will fail.

UPDATE:

The question is not too clear on what the context is (i.e. is the code supposed to work in a live production system or just a DB setup script) and from the comments it seems hard-coding the ID might not be an option. While the code above should normally work fine in the DB initialization scripts where the hierarchy root ID might need to be known and constant, in case of a forest (several roots with IDs not known in advance) the following should work as intended:

```
create table dbo.Foo
(
ID int primary key identity,
ParentID int not null foreign key references foo(ID)
)
go

insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))
```

Then one could query the last identity as usual (`SCOPE_IDENTITY`, etc.). To address @usr's concerns, the code is in fact transactionally safe as the following example demonstrates:

```
insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))
insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))
insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))

select * from dbo.Foo

select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo')
begin transaction   
    insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))
    rollback

select IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo')

insert dbo.Foo (parentId) values (IDENT_CURRENT('dbo.Foo'))

select * from dbo.Foo
```

The result:

```
ID          ParentID
----------- -----------
1           1
2           2
3           3

currentIdentity
---------------------------------------
3

currentIdentity
---------------------------------------
4

ID          ParentID
----------- -----------
1           1
2           2
3           3
5           5
```

Comment: This relies on the first ID being 1 which is not guaranteed. A failing insert (timeout) could destroy the first ID value rendering the table permanently broken.

Comment: @usr That relies on the identity being used with the default seed of 1 as was used in the question. Replace the seed in both places and it still works. It's mentioned in the answer too. I'm however quite interested in the details of the scenario where this would fail leaving the table broken, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Insert a row into the table, rollback the transaction. This will waste one identity value. Identity values never rollback for reasons of concurrency.

Comment: @usr The table would not be "broken" in the situation, you would simply have a different current identity, which can be worked around in a multitude of ways.

Comment: Yeah it requires querying the current identity value. That's awkward and not transactionally consistent. There is no way to atomically query the value and insert a row. I think that almost any code relying on the exact value of the next identity value is fundamentally broken. There might be exceptions but this case is not one of them for the reasons I stated.

Comment: @usr In my experience self-referenced tables are typically initialized in DB setup scripts, where none of the concerns you mention matters. Anyway, I think we're starting to discuss opinions rather than facts.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use an explicit value for the first ID, when you insert your first record, you can disable the checking of the IDENTITY value (see: [MSDN: SET IDENTITY_INSERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)).

Here's an example that illistrates this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  ID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT MyTable_ID FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES MyTable(ID)
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON;
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, ParentID)
VALUES (1, 1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF;

WHILE @@IDENTITY <= 5
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MyTable (ParentID)
    VALUES (@@IDENTITY);
END;

SELECT *
  FROM MyTable;

IF OBJECT_ID('MyTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE MyTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the `NOT NULL` constraint is not true for the root node in the tree. It simply does not have a parent. So the assumption that `ParentID` is `NOT NULL` is broken from the beginning.

I suggest you make it nullable and add an index on `ParentID` to validate that there is only one with value `NULL`:

```
create unique nonclustered index ... on T (ParentID) where (ParentID IS NULL)
```

It is hard to enforce a sound tree structure in SQL Server. You can get multiple roots for example or cycles in the graph. It is hard to validate all that and it is unclear if it is worth the effort. It might well be, depending on the specific case.

Comment: Of course, one would need to be on SQL Server 2008+ to be able to use filtered indices...

Comment: Interesting solution but the customer is on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @Nezreli I can recommend using a trigger, then. A trigger can look at inserted rows to verify basically anything. It could look like this: `IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T WHERE ParentID IS NULL) > 1 RAISEERROR`